# Chrome version 59.0.3071.115 anonymous behavior on text field

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In our application, we have two input boxes to add the user's account number and confirm the account number. On focus, we set the input type to text and on blur or out of focus, we are hiding the input, by changing its type to password. Also, we are formatting the account number using https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin

When the users type the account number `34982017`, we format it to `349-2017`.

Currently, our implementation works on all browsers on all devices(desktop, mobile, and tablet). But a few people, who don't use Chrome 59.0.3071.115 are not able to tab to the 'confirm account' field. The browser is not allowing to move to the next field via tab or mouse event.

Then when we tried to browse the app in incognito mode with that particular version, the app works fine.

Later we flushed the cookies, local Storage and session storage still we are not able to move to the next field in normal mode.

Does the browser work differently in incognito apart from not storing the data or cache?

This particular issue is not happening on other versions of Chrome and on IE.

Comment: Would it be sufficient not just supplying a tab index? ie. `<input type="text" tabindex="3"></input>`. Or do you literally mean tabbing is disabled?